# How to implement a jsonArray to extended button array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, soap

I have a Hotel class which extended as button with some values in it. I am sharing it below.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Hotel extends Button{
    String  id;
    String name;
    String company_id;

    public Hotel(Context context, String id, String name, String company_id) {
        super(context);
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.company_id = company_id;
    }
}
```

I have an other class to call soap web service which return hotels as json string. 
I am tring to get json hotel array as a hotel array and return it as an array. But when i run app it says "your application stopped". How can i get solved this problem? I think its something about Context. I am sharing the service class and the class i am calling the getHotels Method.

The ServiceManager Class Which i use soap and jsonArray

```
import android.content.Context;    
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;    
    public class ServiceManager {
        private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetHotels";
        private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetHotels";
        private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.170/HotelApps_WebServices.asmx";

        SoapObject soapObject;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope;
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE;

        public static Context mContext;
        public ServiceManager(Context context){
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        public Hotel[] GetHotels(int Company_id) {

            soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            soapObject.addProperty("Company_id", Company_id);

            soapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapSerializationEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

            httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            httpTransportSE.debug = true;

            Hotel hotels[]=new Hotel[6];
            try {
                httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapSerializationEnvelope);
                SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive=(SoapPrimitive)soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
                JSONArray jsonHotels = new JSONArray(soapPrimitive.toString());

                for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                    hotels[i]=new Hotel( mContext, jsonHotels.getJSONObject(i).getString("Hotel_id"),jsonHotels.getJSONObject(i).getString("Hotel_Name"), jsonHotels.getJSONObject(i).getString("Company_id"));

                }
                return hotels;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return hotels;
            }
        }

    }
```

and this is where i call the getHotels method

```
package com.example.arzucaki.sherwoodhotels;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridLayout;

public class Hotels extends AppCompatActivity {

    Hotel hotels[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotels);
        GridLayout glHotels=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.glHotels);

        Thread getHotels=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ServiceManager service=new ServiceManager(getApplicationContext());
                hotels=service.GetHotels(1);
            }
        });
        getHotels.start();
        for (int i=0; i<hotels.length; i++) {
            glHotels.addView(hotels[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the logcat exception

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.arzucaki.sherwoodhotels, PID: 5656
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: *it says "your application stopped".* show your log

Comment: Show your logcat error.

Comment: Your question is also misleading, it should be something like `failing to parse JSON into an object`

Comment: I watched the debug there is no error no problem of getting the hotel array and getting the button hotels.

Comment: Can you share exception log?

Comment: @arzucaki where you initialized hotels in your Hotels activity? in for loop hotels.length cause nullpointer exception, check my below answer

Comment: You've been asked **THREE** times to share your exception log, why don't you just post it so we can know exactly what and where the error is? It is basically just a guessing game now...

Comment: added logcat exeption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is issue because of your array hotels[] not initialized and you trying to access in for loop. so it is throwing nullpointer exception.

You should use AsyncTask instead of Thread, modify you code like:

```
   public class Hotels extends AppCompatActivity {

        Hotel hotels[];

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotels);
            GridLayout glHotels=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.glHotels);
            new HotelInfo().execute();

        }

        private class HotelInfo extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    ServiceManager service=new ServiceManager(getApplicationContext());
                    hotels=service.GetHotels(1);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    if(hotels != null){
                        for (int i=0; i<hotels.length; i++) {
                            glHotels.addView(hotels[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Hope it help you !

Comment: it didnt work it is the same with your code it stops.

Comment: can you post your crash log?

Comment: log cat that you posted it because of array null, so it resolve after apply my answer , can you check after used my answer what the crash log

Comment: added to the question Vikas

Comment: sorry vikas it is my fault i put the     GridLayout glHotels=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.glHotels); in to the calling method it works but as same with the Vijays answer the buttons are not clickable and seems like an shadow but thats an other problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad to help you ! For your another problem clicklistener is not working on button because you did not added any listener on button, so you should add clicklistener on button before added into glHotels.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception. Re-factor your code like this.

```
Thread getHotels=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ServiceManager service=new ServiceManager(getApplicationContext());
            hotels=service.GetHotels(1);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
              for (int i=0; i<hotels.length; i++) {
               glHotels.addView(hotels[i]);
             }
            }
           });
        }
    });
```

But you can use AsyncTask to handle UI better.

Comment: Your code works Vijay but buttons are not buttons they are like a black empty shadows and not clickable.

Comment: Thanks a lot vijay i handled it with AsyncTask but your answer worked too. İ am going to accept Vikas anwers as correct answer cu he writed first.